# "Allow text to overflow shape" in excel 2010 vba

Tags: vba, excel

Could I please be pointed to how I could target the "Allow Text to Overflow Shape" of a Textbox created via VBA using AddShape? I have looked through the object reference textframe/textframe2 with no luck.

This can be achieved without vba[but I have lots of textboxes] by:

right click [on the textbox shape] >> format shape >> textbox >> Allow Text to overflow shape [tick box under the "Autofit" group]

I have also done macro recording to no avail

Suggestions much appreciated

Comment: Thanks R3uK, the answer below seem to address my need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The setting you refer to seem to affect two properties in the Excel object model, `TextFrame.HorizontalOverflow` and `TextFrame.VerticalOverflow`.

`VerticalOverflow` can be set to:

- `xlOartVerticalOverflowClip` - no overflow
- `xlOartVerticalOverflowEllipsis` - overflow is marked with three dots (**...**)
- `xlOartVerticalOverflowOverflow` - allows overflow

`HorizontalOverflow` can only be set to:

- `xlOartHorizontalOverflowClip` - no overflow
- `xlOartHorizontalOverflowOverflow` - allows overflow

Working example (Excel 2010):

```
Sheet1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.VerticalOverflow = xlOartVerticalOverflowOverflow
```

**EDIT**:

Also see the documentation at MSDN, where it says that the [VerticalOverflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837403%28v=office.15%29.aspx) setting only has an effect when the `AutoSize` property is **False**, and that the [HorizontalOverflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196543.aspx) setting only has an effect when the `TextFrame2.WordWrap` property is **msoFalse** (0).

Comment: OK, great! I added a reference to the documentation at MSDN as well.

Answer (score 1):

If shapes are small, it’s better to set both vertical and horizontal to overflow.

```
Sheet1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.VerticalOverflow = xlOartVerticalOverflowOverflow
Sheet1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.HorizontalOverflow=xlOartHorizontalOverflowOverflow
Sheet1.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoFalse
```