# allow text to overflow cell excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

How can I allow text to overflow a cell in excel?

I found this for vba:

["Allow text to overflow shape" in excel 2010 vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998838/allow-text-to-overflow-shape-in-excel-2010-vba)

I would like to do the equivalent of `xlOartHorizontalOverflowOverflow` - allows overflow, but in C# and to overflow a cell (instead of a shape)

I have tried:

```
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.OverflowText = true;

worksheet.Cells[1, 1].AllowEditOverflow = true;

worksheet.Cells[1, 1].TextFrame2.HorizontalOverflow = true;

worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = Excel.xlOartHorizontalOverflowOverflow;

worksheet.Cells[1, 1].TextFrame2.HorizontalOverflow = Excel.xlOartHorizontalOverflowOverflow;
```

but none work

Any help would be appretiated

Comment: The link shows how to allow text to overflow a shape, but you're trying to do it on a cell.

Comment: @stuartd yes, but I would like to do that on a cell, with C#

Comment: I suggest you do what you want to do to the cell in Excel while recording it as a macro, then look at the macro to see what was set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.WrapText = false;
```