# Excel vba how to check if textframe is overflowing

Tags: excel, vba, text, overflow

how can i check if the text in an excel shape textframe is overflowing?

Found this Word vba [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.textframe.overflowing), but it's not working in excel:

```
Set myTBox = ActiveDocument.Shapes("MyTextBox") 
If myTBox.TextFrame.Overflowing = True Then
```

I get the "Object doesn't support this property or method"-error.

Any solution?

Comment: Textboxes in Excel are not exactly the same as textboxes in Word (ask Microsoft). AFAIK there is no way to check to see if the characters in a `TextFrame` within a `Textbox` are overflowing. There are [properties to allow both vertical and horizontal overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30999474/4717755). The reason for your error, however, is that `Shapes` are associated with a specific `Sheet` (the `ActiveDocument` is specific to Word, you'd use `ActiveWorkbook` in Excel).

Comment: #PeterT: I didn't use "ActiveDocument", my code was this: If myWs.Shapes("My.shape").TextFrame.Overflowing = True Then.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no `Overflowing`-property in Excel. However, you can write your own function to check.

The following function saves the dimension (width and height) of the textbox and temporarily set the `AutoSize`-property. If either the widht or the height of the shape increases, the text didn't fit into the box. Note that it is depending on the `WordWrap`-propety if the widht or the height changes.

After checking, the AutoSize-property and the dimensions of the shape are reset.

The test sub sets the color of the shape to red if the text doesn't fit, else to green.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = Sheet1.Shapes(1)
    If checkOverflow(sh) Then
        sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    Else
        sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    End If
End Sub

Function checkOverflow(sh As Shape) As Boolean
    If sh.TextFrame2.AutoSize <> msoAutoSizeNone Then Exit Function
    
    Dim saveWidth As Double, saveHeight As Double
    ' Save the current size
    saveWidth = sh.Width
    saveHeight = sh.Height
    ' Check if size increases 
    sh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
    checkOverflow = (saveWidth < sh.Width) Or (saveHeight < sh.Height)
    ' Reset everything
    sh.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeNone
    sh.Width = saveWidth
    sh.Height = saveHeight
End Function
```

Comment: On the possibility of the textbox "flickering" during the function, would disabling `ScreenUpdating` during execution work? Or would that need to be enabled to allow the textbox to resize?

Comment: I couldn't see any flickering. Setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` didn't affect functionality.

Comment: I was randomly wondering if this was possible - very neat solution, but probably not something truly scalable if you need to resize every cell to check. +1 nonetheless

Comment: @Dean: It's not about cells, it's about shapes. Usually, you shouldn't have more than a few shapes on a sheet.

Comment: I realise after I commented - my application was with cells themselves and not shapes. Sorry!